# How to catch click event in backbone

Tags: events, backbone.js, click

I want to catch the button's (addnewItem) click event but can't achieve it. What is wrong with the following code?

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "table",
    render: function () {
        var rows = [];
        this.collection.each(function (row) {
            var rowView = new RowView({ model: row});
            rows.push(rowView.render().el);
        });
        this.$el.html(rows);
        $("#app-view").html("<h3>Items</h3><br/>").append(this.el).append("<br /><input type='button' class='btn btn-primary' value='Add new item' id='addNewItem' />");
        return this;
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.render);
    },
    events: {
        "click #addNewItem": "addNewItem"
    },
    addNewItem: function () {
        alert('Item added');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view only catches events this way if they originate inside the view's `el`. I can see from your render method that the button is outside the `el`.

If it works in your html, you could fix this just by including your button in the `el` (which I think is just a default div). Your render method might now end with:

```
this.$el.html(rows).append("<br /><input type='button' class='btn btn-primary' value='Add new item' id='addNewItem' />");
$("#app-view").html("<h3>Items</h3><br/>").append(this.el);
return this;
```

An alternative is attaching the event in a more conventional way. In your `initialize` method you could add:

```
$("#app-view").on('click', '#addNewItem', this.addNewItem);
```

or, if the `this` keyword is important in the `addNewItem` method then try:

```
$("#app-view").on('click', '#addNewItem', this.addNewItem.bind(this));
```

Comment: First one didn't work but alternative one made it. Many thanks! But I still wonder; why first approach (neither mine nor your solution) don't work as expected.

Comment: In your initial code, the fact that `#addNewItem` was outside the `el` was definitely a factor. The view doesn't "listen" to the whole DOM, only what it contains. This is a good feature - for example that means each of your row views can catch their own events without accidentally catching those from other rows.